# AJAX naming conventions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a web app with a lot of files that I call via jQuery. My main scripts reside in the top-level directory, and my ajax scripts reside in /ajax.

Most of the AJAX scripts I write tend to have a single function, and so I name them appropriately (i.e. add_user.php, process_cc_payment.php). But depending on what I'm doing with it, they tend to vary wildly and there's no rhyme or reason to their names. Is there a standard practice for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There no single standard practice for this, just follow some basic rules (*your* rules that *you* and your team follow, this is my general list):

- Above all do what works for you and your team
- Keep the names descriptive as possible, but not too verbose
- I personally try and name them with *some* sort of convention, for example all payment stuff could be `payment_xxxx.php`, again do what works *for you* here

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to organize the methods and put it together.Ex: Have a file for all methods of user (add user,update user,get user,delete user etc..) Use querystring values to discriminate which function to be called.I usually add a handler suffix to the file names and keep it under the handler folder under my Library(Lib) folder

Lib\handlers\userhandler.php

Lib\handlers\coursehandler.php